# Reg ex help for a long string

Tags: regex, jmeter

Hoping people can help with the following issue I'm having. Trying to get out the following from a response body for jmeter tests, and am struggling with the reg ex commands to do it, could someone help.

> =\u3126wctx=**WsFedOwinState%3uG00JhYpjs2OMg1b26LgxN9FraX5JkCMJIzS3PADRcklVOCFBuG_YeFge5BBjnXmuFJHgudnhr_4DrvYq66r6bUg0UrOsIIAUvUa-6bea08ciu4KUfklDJSXPLu_tkQzMYoDhngbXAbZXrOBICWR3bsuu0xtxbR9fxoZzfRTFylaeI**\u0026wa=wsignin1.0

I need everything in bold retrieving. I've tried using `=` at the start of the regex, but because there are multiple `=` in the response before the one I need, it doesn't latch onto the right one. Similarly I could use help with the end where it should stop at the last alphanumerical character before the `\` .

very much appreciate anyone's response, I've been looking at this for a number of hours to no avail!

Comment: You need to define some sort of anchors otherwise the problem is unresolveable. Will `wctx=` always precede the "bolded part"? Will something always terminate it -- for example, a character other than `[A-Za-z0-9_%-]`? What's the syntax of the segment? Which regex definition are you using -- e.g. grep, perl, gawk, etc.? (maybe it's jmeter, I don't know jmeter so I can't tell.)

Comment: Try using a capturing group ^=[\w+%\\-]*=([\w+%-]+)\\ See https://regex101.com/r/g9jDn6/1

Answer (score 0):

This matches everything between `=` and `\`:

```
(?<==)[^=]+(?=\\)
```

`[^=]` means “any character not an equals sign”, so the match doesn’t start at the first character.

The quantified `+` is used to require at least one character so you don’t get a match between the first 2 chars.

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter you can use Boundary Extractors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PONyo.png)

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: There should be more description upon the answer given by you, please edit it, or delete it, because the answers should be as comprehensive as the problem described, .... you could simply add a comment below the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want regular expression it would be as simple as `wctx=(.+?)\\`

[image]

Also since [JMeter 4.0](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-4-0-released-td5727575.html) there is [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) which might be easier to use as you need just to supply left and right boundaries and JMeter will extract everything in-between, moreover it acts faster and consumes less resources. Check out [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/) for more details:

[image]